# Double sorting by two criterions using Sort

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I was sorting a list of pairs of numbers firstly by second number then by first number. I wanted to use `Sort` since we can use `#1` and `#2` there so it could provide more control over it **in cases of complicated criterions**.

The simplest "double sorting" code I was able to achieve with `Sort` is below. I wanted to avoid `SortBy` because it does not provide `#2` which might be handicap with **more complicated criterions**.

Any better idea with using `Sort` for such problems?

```
li = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[5], {2}]]

SortBy[li, {#[[2]] &, #[[1]] &}]

Flatten[Sort[#, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] & /@ 
   SplitBy[Sort[li, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &], #[[2]] &], 1] == %

(* {{5,4},{4,3},{4,1},{1,4},{5,1},{4,4},{2,2},{4,5},{1,2},{1,5},{3,2},{1,3},{5,5},{3,3},{3,4},{5,2},{2,3},{4,2},{2,5},{1,1},{3,5},{3,1},{2,1},{5,3},{2,4}} *)
(* {{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1},{1,2},{2,2},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{5,3},{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4},{5,4},{1,5},{2,5},{3,5},{4,5},{5,5}} *)
(* True *)
```

**Update:**

Although I mentioned above that I need the double sorting also for **more complicated criterions** I provided example that is simple enough that can be sorted by methods that would not work for **more complicated examples**, so here is another example...

We are sorting firstly by sinus of second number then by sinus of first number:

The last line in the code is what I was looking for - it uses only one `Sort`:

(PS: and I am aware that the sorting might not always be unique but the chosen example has unique solution so you can test your methods)

```
li = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[5], {2}]]

SortBy[li, {Sin[#[[2]] // N] &, Sin[#[[1]] // N] &}]

Flatten[Sort[#, Sin[#1[[1]]] < Sin[#2[[1]]] &] & /@ 
  SplitBy[Sort[li, Sin[#1[[2]]] < Sin[#2[[2]]] &], #[[2]] &], 1]

Sort[li, Sin[#1[[2]]] < Sin[#2[[2]]] || 
   Sin[#1[[2]]] == Sin[#2[[2]]] && Sin[#1[[1]]] < Sin[#2[[1]]] &]

%%% == %% == %

(* True *)
```

Comment: `Sort[li, Order @@ {#, #2}[[All , {2, 1}]] &]`?

Comment: Or `Reverse /@ Sort[Reverse@li]`

Comment: Maybe I should have used more complicated example, where you have to use functions on `#1` and `#2` to compare them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it was obvious but had a hard time to figure it out using single `Sort`...

```
li = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[5], {2}]];
SortBy[li, {#[[2]] &, #[[1]] &}];
Flatten[Sort[#, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] & /@ 
   SplitBy[Sort[li, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &], #[[2]] &], 1] == %

Sort[li, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] || #1[[2]] == #2[[2]] && #1[[1]] < #2[[1]]&] == %%

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

li = RandomSample[Tuples[Range[5], {2}]]

(* {{5, 3}, {1, 5}, {5, 2}, {4, 2}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 
  2}, {1, 4}, {4, 1}, {3, 1}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {2, 
  1}, {3, 3}, {5, 1}, {1, 3}, {4, 4}, {3, 5}, {2, 2}, {4, 5}, {2, 3}} *)

sort1 = SortBy[li, {#[[2]] &, #[[1]] &}];

sort2 = Flatten[
   Sort[#, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &] & /@ 
    SplitBy[Sort[li, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &], #[[2]] &], 1];

sort3 = Sort[ReverseSort@li, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &];

sort4 = Sort[Reverse@Sort@li, #1[[2]] < #2[[2]] &]

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 
  2}, {5, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 
  4}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}} *)

sort1 === sort2 === sort3 === sort4

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use a "Which" statement that inspects all possible cases.

```
Sort[li, Which[#1[[2]] < #2[[2]], True, #1[[2]] == #2[[2]], #1[[1]] <= #2[[1]], #1[[2]] > #2[[2]], False] &]

{{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 
  2}, {5, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}, {4, 3}, {5, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 
  4}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 5}, {3, 5}, {4, 5}, {5, 5}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `If` in `Sort` or `Reverse` in `SortBy`.

With `li` in OP

```
Sort[li
 , If[Equal@@ Map[Last, {##}]
    , Less@@ Map[First, {##}]
    , Less@@ Map[Last, {##}]
   ] &
]
```

Or

```
SortBy[li, Reverse]
```

Hope this helps.